# error: cannot find symbol "tri.CalArea();"

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Area
{
double a;
double b;

void CalArea()
{
    System.out.println("invoke");
}
}


class Square extends Area
{
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
void CalArea()
{
    System.out.println("Enter the value of the side:");
    a=sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("The Area of the square is "+(a*a)+" sq units");
}
}

class Triangle extends Area
{
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
void CalArea()
{
    System.out.println("Enter the values of the height and breadth:");
    a=sc.nextDouble();
    b=sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("The Area of the triangle is "+(0.5*a*b)+" sq units");
}
}

 class Rectangle extends Area
 {
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      void CalArea()
      {
           System.out.println("Enter the value of sides of the rectangle:");
            a=sc.nextDouble();
             b=sc.nextDouble();
           System.out.println("The Area of the square is "+(a*b)+" sq units");
      }
  }

   class Override
   {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
           Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
              System.out.println("Enter a choice to find 1. area of square 2. area of triangle 3. area of rectangle 4. exit");
               int ch=sc.nextInt();
               switch(ch)
               {
            case 1: Area sq=new Square();
                sq.CalArea();
            case 2: Area t=new Triangle();
                  tri.CalArea();
            case 3: Area rec=new Rectangle();
                rec.CalArea();
            case 4: break;
            default: System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
    }
}
```

when i try to run it it shows an error
error: cannot find symbol
tri.CalArea();
^
symbol:   variable tri
location: class Override
1 error

error: cannot find symbol
tri.CalArea();

symbol:   variable tri
location: class Override

and I am not able to figure out, please help me

Comment: Don't put nonsense text into your questions.  It is disrespectful to the people you want to help you.

Comment: The problem is that you declared the variable (on the previous line!) as `t` not `tri`.

Comment: there is no 'tri' variable in your code. That is what system says to you - can not find symbol tri. You declared variable 't' one line of code above this error. So use t or change name to tri.

Comment: Don't forget to write `break;` after each individual case in your `switch`.

Comment: change: `Area t=new Triangle();` to this: `Area tri = new Triangle();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix the error in your variable name for case 2 (triangle).
Also do add the **break** for the switch case else it will execute all subsequent cases.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Area
{
    double a;
    double b;

    void CalArea()
    {
        System.out.println("invoke");
    }
}


class Square extends Area
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    void CalArea()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the value of the side:");
        a=sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("The Area of the square is "+(a*a)+" sq units");
    }
}

class Triangle extends Area
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    void CalArea()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the values of the height and breadth:");
        a=sc.nextDouble();
        b=sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("The Area of the triangle is "+(0.5*a*b)+" sq units");
    }
}

 class Rectangle extends Area
 {
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      void CalArea()
      {
           System.out.println("Enter the value of sides of the rectangle:");
            a=sc.nextDouble();
            b=sc.nextDouble();
           System.out.println("The Area of the square is "+(a*b)+" sq units");
      }
  }

class Override
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a choice to find 1. area of square 2. area of triangle 3. area of rectangle 4. exit");
        int ch=sc.nextInt();
        switch(ch) {
            case 1: 
                Area sq=new Square();
                sq.CalArea();
                break;
            case 2: 
                Area tri=new Triangle();
                tri.CalArea();
                break;
            case 3: 
                Area rec=new Rectangle();
                rec.CalArea();
                break;
            default: 
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
    }
}
```